# How to guarantee uniqueness of field's value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table looking like this:

```
id      bigint,
user_id bigint,
main    boolean,
...
```

Of all entries with same `user_id` only one can have `main = true`.
Please, advice, how to realize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name (user_id) WHERE main;
```